# How do you place an exisiting SQLite database into an application's local data store for use in a Universal Windows Platform application?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sqlite, uwp

I have successfully followed the instructions to work with SQLite databases in a Universal Windows Platform application, as explained here:  ["Use a SQLite database in a UWP app"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-access/sqlite-databases)

That tutorial shows how to create a new SQLite database, with C# code, in the application's local data store, but it does not explain how to put an existing SQLite database into the local data store.

Comment: Putting a existing DB into store is pointless if it lacks data. SqlLight is usually used as Near client part of a Distributed Database, so creating it on first start would be enough.

Comment: The database I have and will use is not empty.  It's loaded with data for use in the application.

Comment: Then the DB file would really just be a normal file like any Image or Localisation file | Also it is rather odd that it does contain data already.

Comment: The database contains reference information only, which the application will use for various calculations.  It will be a read only database, as the user will not edit, add, or delete any data.

Comment: If it is only soome lookup tables, I would propably have kept it simpler then a DB. Information that is static or at least not modified (during transfer) is hte one case where I would use a CSV or XML file for storage. | It is actually a wierd case. I am normally the one advising people to leave those files (or access/excel) behind, because their operation clearly outgrew the limits of them and went into a full on database realm. But this is a rare case where they would be fitting and propably future proof. A case where the DB itself can cause more trouble then it can save.

Comment: Christopher - Thank you for your comments. In response I may follow your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how to put an existing SQLite database into the local data store.

The database is also a db file, so this question can be translated into how to copy file to local storage.

Here is the code:

```cs
public async Task<StorageFile> CopyFileToLocalStorage(StorageFile dbFile)
{
    var localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    var localFile = await dbFile.CopyAsync(localFolder, "sqliteSample.db",NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    return localFile;
}
```

Best regards.